# Issues with Angular Dropdown List - dynamically select an option when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular

Am using Angular Reactive form and I have a dropdown list and a input field. I have a list of object called `Category: {id, name, parent}`. This list is displayed in a table which has `edit button/link` in each row. when a particular row's `edit link` is clicked, I want the data in that row to fill the input field and the select option will be selected automatically.

For example here are my form and Component:

```
<form [formGroup]="childCategoryForm" (ngSubmit)="saveOrUpdateChildCategory(childCategoryForm.value)" autoComplete="off">
          <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'error': !validateParentCategory()}">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2" for="parent">Parent Category</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" class="form-control" formControlName="parent" name="parent" id="parent">
                <option [ngValue]=null>--- select parent category ---</option>
                <option [ngValue]="parent" *ngFor="let parent of parentCategories">{{parent.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'error': !validateCategoryName()}"> <!--  && categoryForm.controls.name?.errors.pattern -->
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2" for="name">Category Name</label>
            <!--em *ngIf="!validateCategoryName()">Required</em>
            <em *ngIf="!validateCategoryName()">Required</em-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Category name..." />
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="childCategoryFormEditMode">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-2" for="name"></label>
            <div class="btn-toolbar col-md-6">
              <button type="button" (click)="cancelEditChildrenCategory()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mr-2">Cancel edit</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit edit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>



<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Parent</th>
              <th scope="col">Edit</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let child of childrenCategories; index as i">
              <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
              <td>{{child.name}}</td>
              <td>{{child.parent['name']}}</td>
              <td class="text-primary"><a class="deco-none" (click)="editChildCategory(child)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</a></td>
              <td class="text-danger"><a class="deco-none" (click)="deleteCategory(child)" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

When a user clicks on the Edit link, I want the contents in that row to populate the form above. The means that parent column will be used to select the corresponding select option in the form.

The component looks like this:

```
export class AddCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  name: FormControl;
  parent: FormControl;
  childCategoryForm: FormGroup;
  selectedValue: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.parent = new FormControl(this.selectedValue);
    this.name = new FormControl('');
    this.childCategoryForm = new FormGroup({name: this.name, parent: this.parent});
  }

// THIS IS THE MAIN FUNCTION WHERE I AM TRYING TO DYNAMICALLY SELECT AN  OPTION BASED ON THE VALUES IN THE ROW CLICKED BY THE USER. THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT IS CALLED WHEN A USER CLICKS ON THE EDIT LINK

 editChildCategory(category: Category) {
    this.selectedValue = category.parent;
    // this.childCategoryForm.setValue({name: category.name, parent: category.parent});
    this.childCategoryForm.controls['name'].setValue(category.name);
    this.childCategoryForm.controls['parent'].setValue(category.parent['name']);
     this.selectedValue = category.parent['name'];
  }

}
```

Some of the code in the above function are in comment because I have been trying different things but it's not working.

Comment: To me how you are setting the value prop of select is the prob. Change html to `<option [ngValue]="parent.name" *ngFor="let parent of parentCategories">`.

Comment: @User3250 thanks for your comment. You are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me how you are setting the value prop of select is the prob.
Change html to below:

```
<option [ngValue]="parent.name" *ngFor="let parent of parentCategories">
```

Since, parent is an object not a string value to which you could match later on when edit link is clicked. Hope this helps!